# Visual Studio + Nsight : __syncthreads() undefined

Tags: cuda

The question is already present but i m having the same problems and the answer doesn't resolve it

[Cuda __syncthreads undefined. Without it-> random results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844624/cuda-syncthreads-undefined-without-it-random-results)

When i use __syncthreads() intellisense says it undefined. 
Is there another was to synchronize threads ?

Comment: Intellisense says it is undefined but your program should [compile and run fine with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893919/cuda-syncthreads-compiles-fine-but-is-underlined-with-red).  If you do a google search on "cuda red underline" you'll get a variety of hits with suggestions on how to fix this issue.  But you should be able to safely ignore the red underline in this case.

Comment: Intellisense is not a compiler. It says **undefined** for most of the device intrinsics.

Comment: then what is the point of intellisense